# ASP.NET Change Text and Color in Gridview cell in a Template Field

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have Gridview in ASP.net that displays data. Depending on the data it changes color and text depending on the value of the cell.
This works fine when a column is NOT a template field.

```
 //WORKS WHEN IS NOT A TEMPLATE FIELD
 if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
 {
        if (e.Row.Cells[2].Text == "1")
        {

           e.Row.Cells[2].Text = "IN";
           e.Row.Cells[2].BackColor = Color.Blue;
           e.Row.Cells[2].ForeColor = Color.White;
        }

  }
```

Now I converted the Column in to a Template field and nothing works.

```
     //DOEST NOT WORK WHEN IS a TEMPLATE FIELD
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
         if (e.Row.Cells[2].Text == "1")
         {

             e.Row.Cells[2].Text = "IN";
             e.Row.Cells[2].BackColor = Color.Blue;
             e.Row.Cells[2].ForeColor = Color.White;
         }

     }
```

I GOT THE COLOR WORKING, but now I need to change the Text to the following. IF statusID == 1 then display IN, else if statusID == 2 then display OUT

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="StatusID" SortExpression="StatusID">
                            <EditItemTemplate>
                                <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" SelectedValue = '<%# Bind("StatusID") %>'>
                                    <asp:ListItem Value="1">IN</asp:ListItem>
                                    <asp:ListItem Value="2">OUT</asp:ListItem>
                                </asp:DropDownList>
                            </EditItemTemplate>
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <asp:Label ID="lblStatus" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("StatusID") %>' ForeColor='<%# Convert.ToString(Eval("StatusID")) == "1" ? System.Drawing.Color.Green: Convert.ToString(Eval("StatusID")) == "2" ? System.Drawing.Color.Red: System.Drawing.Color.Purple%>'></asp:Label>
                            </ItemTemplate>
                        </asp:TemplateField>
```

Any of you know how to solve this issue. Thanks in advance.

Comment: add text of column to label in template field and find the control and change the control

Comment: Can you elaborate further?

Comment: can u put ur gridview code.....i mean design code?

Comment: Code is up. I got the color working see the ItemTemplate, now I need the text to change. Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The reason doesn't work in template column is status value is null. Try the following.

```
// In template column,
if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
{
   var status = (Label)e.Row.FindControl("lblStatus");
   if (status.Text == "1")
   {
      e.Row.Cells[2].Text = "IN";
      e.Row.Cells[2].BackColor = Color.Blue;
      e.Row.Cells[2].ForeColor = Color.White;
   }
}
```

Or cast DataItem to appropiate object and get the status value.

[GridViewRow.DataItem Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridviewrow.dataitem.aspx)

```
// In template column,
if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
{
   var obj = (MyObject)e.Row.DataItem;
   if (obj.Status == 1)
   {
      e.Row.Cells[2].Text = "IN";
      e.Row.Cells[2].BackColor = Color.Blue;
      e.Row.Cells[2].ForeColor = Color.White;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
{
  Label lbl=(Label)e.Row.FindControl("lblStatus");
   if (lbl.Text == "1")
   {
      lbl.Text = "IN";
      e.Row.Cells[2].BackColor = Color.Blue;
      e.Row.Cells[2].ForeColor = Color.White;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am a vb programmar here is a sample code.

```
If e.Row.RowType = DataControlRowType.DataRow Then
                Dim abc As Label = TryCast(e.Row.FindControl("label1"), Label)

            If abc.Text = "ADMIN" Then
                e.Row.Cells(7).ForeColor = Drawing.Color.Blue

            End If
        End If
```

i really hope it works.

Answer (score 0):

Use `ItemTemplate` and surround `Eval` with any HTML you need, for example, to change your color.

```
Text='<%# "Your HTML(use FONT COLOR=BLUE)" + Eval("HealthUnit") + "Close your HTML here" %>
```

as, here:

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Health Unit Website">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:HyperLink runat="server" 
                       NavigateUrl='<%# Eval("Website") %>' 
                       tabindex="-1" 
                       Target="_blank" 
                       Text='<%# "<font color=blue><b>" +
                                  Eval("HealthUnit") + 
                                  "</b></font>" %>'>
        </asp:HyperLink>
    </ItemTemplate>
    <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Left" VerticalAlign="Top" width="14%"  />
</asp:TemplateField>
```