# How to set GridView's color text

Tags: asp.net, gridview

I can set for all by using back color but how can i set color to text as follow to be showed in Grid View: Success = green, Process = Red, Verified = Yellow
Thank you all.

```
 <asp:Label ID="Label1" BackColor="#006699" runat="server" 
   Text='<%#Eval("Status").ToString()=="S"?"Success":Eval("Status").ToString()=="V"?"Verified":Eval("Status").ToString()=="A"?"Approved":"Process" %>'></asp:Label>
```

Comment: Duplicate?: [ASP.NET Change Text and Color in Gridview cell in a Template Field](http://stackoverflow.com/q/15907217/456814).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
// Row Data Bound Event fires after gridview calls DataBind() method.
// So if you want to data or check certain conditions before displaying it to the user
// this may be correct place to do the changes.
protected void RowDataBound(Object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
   if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
       var status = (Label)e.Row.FindControl("Label1");
      if(status == "Success")
        (e.Row.FindControl("Label1") as Label).BackColor  = Color.Green;

if(status == "Process")
        (e.Row.FindControl("Label1") as Label).BackColor = Color.Rad;

if(status == "Verified")
        (e.Row.FindControl("Label1") as Label).BackColor = Color.Yellow;
    }
}
```

Or cast DataItem to appropiate object and get the status value.

[GridViewRow.DataItem Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridviewrow.dataitem.aspx)

```
protected void RowDataBound(Object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
       var obj = (MyObject)e.Row.DataItem;
       if(obj.Status == "Success")
        (e.Row.FindControl("Label1") as Label).BackColor  = Color.Green;

if(obj.Status== "Process")
        (e.Row.FindControl("Label1") as Label).BackColor = Color.Rad;

if(obj.Status == "Verified")
        (e.Row.FindControl("Label1") as Label).BackColor = Color.Yellow;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Vignesh, I did apply first code but i got error as: Operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type 'Syste.Web.Ul.WebControls.label' and 'string' any help please? Zey thank you for your post.

Answer (score 1):

Use this on code behind

```
protected void RowDataBound(Object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
if(e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
{
   // Retrieve the underlying data item. In this example
   // the underlying data item is a DataRowView object. 
   DataRowView rowView = (DataRowView)e.Row.DataItem;

   // Retrieve the state value for the current row. 
   String state = rowView["Label1"].ToString();

    //format color of the as below 
    if(state == "Success")
            (e.Row.FindControl("lbl1") as Label).BackColor  = Color.Green;

    if(state == "Process")
            (e.Row.FindControl("lbl1") as Label).BackColor = Color.Rad;

    if(state == "Verified")
            (e.Row.FindControl("lbl1") as Label).BackColor = Color.Yellow;

 }
}
```